# Is it possible to use Python XlsxWriter to write a stock data type to a cell?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, stock

I have an interest in utilizing the stock quote feature of excel while also creating the file using the xlsxwriter libray in Python. I am familiar with how to write and format text using xlsxwriter but I do not see any option to create a file with certain cells already set to have a stock data type. To be clear, the link from microsoft below basically summarizes the manual process I'm looking to have taken care of in the excel sheet before an actual user ever opens up the file.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-a-stock-quote-e5af3212-e024-4d4c-bea0-623cf07fbc54

I am open to other python based solutions to this issue if the general consensus is that xlsxwriter doesn't support this feature. I really appreciate any advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author of XlsxWriter. I just looked into this and these aren't regular Excel formulas. They have a lot of of additional metadata and richdata helper files associated with them and even the company names aren't standard string types. So unfortunately these aren't, and probably won't be, supported.

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback and honesty.  I agree that the functionality has a lot of dependencies and I understand that making something like this work may not be possible. This answers my question.